# Automating Twilio webhook address setting with ngrok address incoming calls

Tags: twilio, webhooks, ngrok

For twilio incoming calls
Currently I manually open a command prompt and run --> ngrok http 5000
I use the http address and manually go to my twilio page number and insert that http address in webhook.

My automation code which accepts incoming Twilio calls run using python flask on port 5000. The code works fine.

I like to automate running --> ngrok http 5000 (this part I can do no problem ).  Then the problem is updating the Twilio webhook address.

I am about to integrate this automation code with CI and it requires that I automatically update the webhook address. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to deploy it somewhere and stop using ngrok.

Comment: What do you mean deploy it somewhere, deploy what?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I though you had some code running on port 5000. I meant you deploy this code.

Comment: I added a bit more info on summary, sorry if it was not clear

Comment: I like to automate running --> ngrok http 5000 (this part I can do no problem ). Then the problem is updating the Twilio webhook address.

Comment: Got it. This tutorial will help you: https://github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/WhatsAppBotTut
Part 3 is where you deploy the Flask app so you have a static URL and never update the webhook on Twilio again.

Comment: I am familiar with Section 5 here --> https://github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/WhatsAppBotTut/blob/master/02.%20Setting%20up%20Webhook%20for%20Incoming%20Messages.ipynb    what I need is to make that seciton automated.  Thats my question

Comment: I think I figured it oout

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the answer to my Q is right here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource?code-sample=code-update-incomingphonenumber-to-include-an-addresssid&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x